# Which Data Structure would be more suitable for the following task in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, fifo

Every `5` minutes, within the 20th minute cycle, I need to retrieve the data. Currently, I'm using the **map** data structure.

Is there a better data structure? Every time I read and set the data, I have to write to the file to prevent program restart and data loss.

For example, if the initial data in the *map* is:

```
{-1:"result1",-2:"result2",-3:"result3",-4:"result4"}
```

I want to get the last `-4` period's value which is `"result4"`, and set the new value "result5", so that the updated *map* will be:

```
{-1:"result5",-2:"result1",-3:"result2",-4:"result3"}
```

And again, I want to get the last `-4` period's value which is `"result3"`, and set the new value `"result6"`, so the *map* will be:

```
{-1:"result6",-2:"result5",-3:"result1",-4:"result2"}
```

*The code:*

```
private static String getAndSaveValue(int a) { 
    //read the map from file
    HashMap<Long,String> resultMap=getMapFromFile();
    String  value=resultMap.get(-4L);

    for (Long i = 4L; i >= 2; i--){
        resultMap.put(Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(i - 2 * i)),resultMap.get(1 - i));
    }
    resultMap.put(-1L,"result" + a);
    //save the map to file
    saveMapToFile(resultMap);

    return value;
}
```

Comment: It seems like your initial four results are reversed.  I'd use a `List`.  Append the new value to the end of the `List`, delete the value at position zero after the first four values, and write the four values to an output file.

Comment: Is the result data type actually a string, or a custom object? How frequent are the file read/writes?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur  the rsult data type a custom object which contains time and resultMsg.Five minute one period

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirement, I think [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) data structure will be suitable for your requirement:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        LinkedList<String> ls=new LinkedList<String>();
        ls.push("result4");
        ls.push("result3");
        ls.push("result2");
        ls.push("result1");
        System.out.println(ls);
        ls.push("result5"); //pushing new value
        System.out.println("Last value:"+ls.pollLast()); //this will return `result4`
        System.out.println(ls);
        ls.push("result6"); //pushing new value
        System.out.println("Last value:"+ls.pollLast());  // this will give you `result3`
        System.out.println(ls);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[result1, result2, result3, result4]
Last value:result4
[result5, result1, result2, result3]
Last value:result3  
[result6, result5, result1, result2]
```

Comment: I find that BlockQueue may be also fit, it that right?

Comment: @flower, yeah, it can also be used if your requirement needs to `wait` for this data structure to become non-empty for retrieval & empty / partial-empty for insertion.

Comment: & also if your data structure needs to have pre-defined capacity, then instead of `LinkedList` you might want to use any implementation of `BlockingQueue` which gives you option of setting initial capacity during initialization.

Comment: @flower It's not advisable to use *concurrent collections* in a single-threaded environment. The better approach will be to wrap the existing general purpose collection with a class in order to impose restrictions on the maximum size of the collection.

Comment: @Ashish Patili,Can queue or  LinkedList  put null object ?My be my object is null.

Comment: @flower , `LinkedList` works well with `null`. I just tried doing `add` & `push` operations, & I can see there is no issue with adding null.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your example, you need a [**FIFO**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)) data structure which has a bounded size.

There's no bounded general purpose implementation of the `Queue` interface in the JDK. Only concurrent implementation could be bounded in size. But if you're not going to use it in a multithreaded environment, it's not the best choice because thread safety doesn't come for free - concurrent collections are slower, and also can create confusing for the reader of your code.

To achieve your goal, I suggest you to use the composition by wrapping [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayDeque.html), which is an array-based implementation of the `Queue` and performs way better than `LinkedList`.

Note that is a preferred approach not to extend `ArrayDeque` (*IS A* relationship) and override its methods `add()` and `offer()`, but include it in a class as a field (*HAS A* relationship), so that all the method calls on the instance of your class will be forwarded to the underlying collection. You can find more information regarding this approach in the item "*Favor composition over inheritance*" of ***Effective Java*** by Joshua Bloch.

```
public class BoundQueue<T> {
    private Queue<T> queue;
    private int limit;
    
    public BoundQueue(int limit) {
        this.queue = new ArrayDeque<>(limit);
        this.limit = limit;
    }
    
    public void offer(T item) {
        if (queue.size() == limit) {
            queue.poll(); // or throw new IllegalStateException() depending on your needs
        }
        queue.add(item);
    }
    
    public T poll() {
        return queue.poll();
    }
    
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return queue.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Comment: ,Can queue or LinkedList put null object ?My be my object is null.

Comment: @flower Firstly, you have to distinguish between interface and implementation. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface  `Queue` is an interface, `LinkedList` is an implementation of the `Queue` and `List`. Regarding the question about `null`, `LinkedList` is the only implementation of the `Queue` which allow `null` values. Why others disallow? Because `Queue` interface offers handy methods that allow to loop up at the first element of the queue without checking if the queue not is empty, `null` is used to indicate the absents of data.

Comment: @flower ... When `null` is considered to be a valid value in a queue it's impossible to distinguish between the cases when the queue is empty and the first value is `null`. And it generally a good practice to avoid using `null` in collections, because you can not extract any useful information from it. If `null` has a special meaning in your business logic that a design flaw. If you want your code to be clear and maintainable, you should design your system treating `null` as a special case, passing `null` arguments and storing `null` values. There are many ways how to approach that.

Comment: @flower ... It's hard to target a problem without knowing the details. For instance if you need to perform a default set of actions when there's no data, in place of using `null` you might consider implementing the *Null-object pattern*.